# Unable to change global variable from local function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to have a jQuery.getJSON() call change a global variable with the JSON array it returns:

```
var photo_info ;

//Advance to the next image
    function changeImage(direction) {

            jQuery('img#preview_image').fadeOut('fast');
            jQuery('#photo_main').css('width','740px');

            if (direction == 'next') {
                    jQuery.getJSON('/ajaxupdate?view&sort='+sort+'&a='+a+'&s=' + title_url_next, function(data) {
                            photo_info = data;
                            title_url = photo_info.title_url;                                                                                          
                            title_url_next = photo_info.preview_title_url_next;                                                                        
                            title_url_previous = photo_info.preview_title_url_previous;                                                                
                    });
            } else if (direction == 'prev') {
                    jQuery.getJSON('/ajaxupdate?view&sort='+sort+'&a='+a+'&s=' + title_url_previous, function(data) {
                            photo_info = data;
                            title_url = photo_info.title_url;
                            title_url_next = photo_info.preview_title_url_next;
                            title_url_previous = photo_info.preview_title_url_previous;
                    });
            }
}
```

However, the variable `photo_info` is only accessible from within the `getJSON()` function and returns undefined from anywhere else in the script.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Randal said Ajax call is asynchronous. Use the ajaxComplete function or replace the getJSON function with an .ajax call and use the photo_info var whithin the success function e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(photo_info);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at `photoinfo` in the rest of the script right after `changeImage` has returned, then of course it won't have a value, because the Ajax call is asynchronous. You need to rethink your application to be more event driven.

Comment: Hi -- photo_info is not accessible even from within the changeImage() function. Thanks.

Comment: Randal is right, because even within the changeImage function the ajax call has not returned yet. See my answer for options on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript scoping isn't quite like standard scoping. It looks like you're actually losing your scope because of nested functions. Try giving this article a read:

http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/